# Reducing noise through interior walls

Tags: drywall, noise

My house is double drywalled. The master bedroom is situated beside my son's bedroom (which is sandwiched between the guest bedroom and the master). We find that when he hits the wall (while sleeping) it is very hollow sounding. I should also add, that I currently have no baseboards (recently got new floors); just not sure if this has anything to do with the noise transmission.

What are some ways to mitigate this (ideally without ripping out any drywall)? I have read about:

- Noise-cancelling drywall adhered with green glue (resulting in a triple drywall)
- Injecting foam insulation into the stud spacings
- Putting up some EPS foam board and drywalling over that

Does anyone have any advice? Maybe there is a simple way to help?

Comment: Check if wall cavity is easily accessible from the ceiling.